# Migration, asp.net 5 rc1 to asp.net core rc2

Tags: asp.net

I Tried to migrate an WEB API from asp.net 5 RC 1 to RC 2

I got thos errors

```
the dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http<="*" could not be resolved



Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not     
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Comment: have you configured the ASP.NET Core Module as specified in this article: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html  under the section 'Working with IIS'

Comment: yes i have . errors are not just in the web service but also in some class libraries

Comment: do you have : <assemblies>
        <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>   
</assemblies>  in your web config?

Comment: no should I have it ?

Comment: give it a try and see if the error persists

Comment: Ok I'll try the web.config it concern just the web service and what about other class libraries ?

Comment: I'm not sure, It just looks like a web config error to me... the class libraries should be fine I think the issue is if you're referencing something in the front end you need the assembly info in the web config..

Comment: I tried that but I still geting the same errors

Comment: Which web.congif have you updated? have you updated the one in Areas->Views->web.config

Comment: the web config inside wwwroot

Comment: When you run the project locally underneath the Compiler error message it should show you the source file...  can you post details of the path?  that will help me to understand where the error is throwing.  I suspect you will need to go into Areas->Views->Web.config and add the assembly there but I can't be sure without that info

Comment: witch path please ?

Comment: When you run the Web API project locally it is going to error in the debugger.  You'll get the option to click ok or continue, if you click continue  you'll see the compilation error in the browser... it will show you the source error and beneath that it will show you the path to the source file... if you can show me that I can tell you exactly where to add the reference

Comment: After lunching the project it still just loading in the browser without showing anything. for the reference can I add it in the project.json ?